# Optimal way to access std::tuple element in runtime by index

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

I have function `at` designed to access std::tuple element by index specified in runtime

```
template<std::size_t _Index = 0, typename _Tuple, typename _Function>
inline typename std::enable_if<_Index == std::tuple_size<_Tuple>::value, void>::type
for_each(_Tuple &, _Function)
{}

template<std::size_t _Index = 0, typename _Tuple, typename _Function>
inline typename std::enable_if < _Index < std::tuple_size<_Tuple>::value, void>::type
    for_each(_Tuple &t, _Function f)
{
    f(std::get<_Index>(t));
    for_each<_Index + 1, _Tuple, _Function>(t, f);
}

namespace detail { namespace at {

template < typename _Function >
struct helper
{
    inline helper(size_t index_, _Function f_) : index(index_), f(f_), count(0) {}

    template < typename _Arg >
    void operator()(_Arg &arg_) const
    {
        if(index == count++)
            f(arg_);
    }

    const size_t index;
    mutable size_t count;
    _Function f;
};

}} // end of namespace detail

template < typename _Tuple, typename _Function >
void at(_Tuple &t, size_t index_, _Function f)
{
    if(std::tuple_size<_Tuple> ::value <= index_)
        throw std::out_of_range("");

    for_each(t, detail::at::helper<_Function>(index_, f));
}
```

It has linear complexity. How can i achive O(1) complexity?

Comment: Are the `tuple` types uniform?

Comment: @Yakk In general case they are not

Comment: I'm not sure if the optimizer could do this, but maybe you can produce a series of `if-else-if-else-if` through metaprogramming that is replaced by a switch/lookup table.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you pass something similar to a generic lambda, i.e. a function object with an overloaded function call operator:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Func
{
    template<class T>
    void operator()(T p)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " : " << p << "\n";
    }
};
```

The you can build an array of function pointers:

```
#include <tuple>

template<int... Is> struct seq {};
template<int N, int... Is> struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};
template<int... Is> struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...> {};

template<int N, class T, class F>
void apply_one(T& p, F func)
{
    func( std::get<N>(p) );
}

template<class T, class F, int... Is>
void apply(T& p, int index, F func, seq<Is...>)
{
    using FT = void(T&, F);
    static constexpr FT* arr[] = { &apply_one<Is, T, F>... };
    arr[index](p, func);
}

template<class T, class F>
void apply(T& p, int index, F func)
{
    apply(p, index, func, gen_seq<std::tuple_size<T>::value>{});
}
```

Usage example:

```
int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, double, char, double> t{1, 2.3, 4, 5.6};
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) apply(t, i, Func{});
}
```

---

clang++ also accepts an expansion applied to a pattern that contains a lambda expression:

```
static FT* arr[] = { [](T& p, F func){ func(std::get<Is>(p)); }... };
```

(although I've to admit that looks really weird)

g++4.8.1 rejects this.

Comment: Building an array of n elements is O(n)

Comment: @Yakk It's static now ;)

Comment: Thank you. I could not compile your code with msvs2013, but idea is clear for me

Comment: @sliser Hmm the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro is non-standard, but the rest shouldn't be too fancy..

Comment: msvs2013 have problem with `using` & `constexpr` keywords

Comment: @sliser: you can replace `using` with a `typedef`: `typedef void (&FT)(T&, F);` and the `constexpr` keyword is not necessary here; `const` will do just fine.