# Boost.Fusion run-time switch

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, boost-fusion

I am reading the type of an object from a file:

```
enum class type_index { ... };
type_index typeidx = read(file_handle, type_index{});
```

Depending on the type index, I want to create a type (out of a list of possible types), and do something generic with it (the same generic code for each type):

```
std::tuple<type1, type2, ..., typeN> possible_types;

boost::fusion::for_each(possible_types, [&](auto i) {
  if (i::typeidx != typeidx) { return; }
  // do generic stuff with i
});
```

That is:

- I have the same generic code for different types,
- I want the compiler to generate specific code for each type,
- I only know which type I need at runtime, and
- I want to execute the code for that single type only.

This feels like a `switch` statement with a run-time condition, but where the "cases" are generated at compile-time. In particular, this does not feel like a `for_each` statement at all (I am not doing anything for all elements in a vector, tuple, list, but only to a single element).

Is there a better clearer way to express/write this idiom? (E.g. use an `mpl::vector` instead of a `std::tuple` for the possible types, use something different than the `for_each` algorithm,...)

Comment: Your example reminded me of the proposed (and I believe rejected) [Boost.Switch](http://dancinghacker.com/switch/) ([Code](http://dancinghacker.com/switch/switch.hpp)). I think [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e25e54d5ab976ce) does something similar to what you want, but I may have misunderstood.

Comment: @cv_and_he : Boost.Switch is a great thought for this. N.b. the library wasn't rejected, but [appears to have been abandoned after being provisionally accepted in Jan 2008](http://osdir.com/ml/lib.boost.announce/2008-01/msg00003.html). :-[ You may want to consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: Are `type_index` contiguous and starting at zero?

Comment: It sounds to me like what you want is exactly what a Boost.Variant offers, plus a factory function which fills this variant initially.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like my usual inherited lambdas trick:

I've written about this before

- [Lambda functions as base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432260/lambda-functions-as-base-classes/18432618#18432618)
- [what is the correct way to handle multiple input command differently in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768152/what-is-the-correct-way-to-handle-multiple-input-command-differently-in-c/17776618#17776618) (where it visits members of a `boost::variant`)

I believe I've seen Sumant Tambe use it in his more recent `cpptruths.com` postings.

---

#### Demonstration

Here's a demo for now. Will add some explanation later.

The most important trick applied is that I use `boost::variant` to hide the type code denum for us. But the principle applies even if you keep your own type discrimination logic (just requiring more coding)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/753ffd26c25a778d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/serialization/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost; // brevity

//////////////////
// This is the utility part that I had created in earlier answers:
namespace util {
    template<typename T, class...Fs> struct visitor_t;

    template<typename T, class F1, class...Fs>
    struct visitor_t<T, F1, Fs...> : F1, visitor_t<T, Fs...>::type {
        typedef visitor_t type;
        visitor_t(F1 head, Fs...tail) : F1(head), visitor_t<T, Fs...>::type(tail...) {}

        using F1::operator();
        using visitor_t<T, Fs...>::type::operator();
    };

    template<typename T, class F> struct visitor_t<T, F> : F, boost::static_visitor<T> {
        typedef visitor_t type;
        visitor_t(F f) : F(f) {}
        using F::operator();
    };

    template<typename T=void, class...Fs>
    typename visitor_t<T, Fs...>::type make_visitor(Fs...x) { return {x...}; }
}

using util::make_visitor;

namespace my_types {
    //////////////////
    // fake types for demo only
    struct A1 {
        std::string data;
    };

    struct A2 {
        double data;
    };

    struct A3 {
        std::vector<int> data;
    };

    // some operations defined on A1,A2...
    template <typename A> static inline void serialize(A& ar, A1& a, unsigned) { ar & a.data; } // using boost serialization for brevity
    template <typename A> static inline void serialize(A& ar, A2& a, unsigned) { ar & a.data; } // using boost serialization for brevity
    template <typename A> static inline void serialize(A& ar, A3& a, unsigned) { ar & a.data; } // using boost serialization for brevity

    static inline void display(std::ostream& os, A3 const& a3) { os << "display A3: " << a3.data.size() << " elements\n"; }
    template <typename T> static inline void display(std::ostream& os, T const& an) { os << "display A1 or A2: " << an.data << "\n"; }

    //////////////////
    // our variant logic
    using AnyA = variant<A1,A2,A3>;

    //////////////////
    // test data setup
    AnyA generate() { // generate a random A1,A2...
        switch (rand()%3) {
            case 0: return A1{ "data is a string here" };
            case 1: return A2{ 42 };
            case 2: return A3{ { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 } };
            default: throw std::invalid_argument("rand");
        }
    }

}

using my_types::AnyA;

void write_archive(std::string const& fname) // write a test archive of 10 random AnyA
{
    std::vector<AnyA> As;
    std::generate_n(back_inserter(As), 10, my_types::generate);

    std::ofstream ofs(fname, std::ios::binary);
    archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);

    oa << As;
}

//////////////////
// logic under test
template <typename F>
void process_archive(std::string const& fname, F process) // reads a archive of AnyA and calls the processing function on it
{
    std::ifstream ifs(fname, std::ios::binary);
    archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);

    std::vector<AnyA> As;
    ia >> As;

    for(auto& a : As)
        apply_visitor(process, a);
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));

    write_archive("archive.txt");

    // the following is c++11/c++1y lambda shorthand for entirely compiletime
    // generated code for the specific type(s) received
    auto visitor = make_visitor(
        [](my_types::A2& a3) { 
                std::cout << "Skipping A2 items, just because we can\n";
                display(std::cout, a3);
            },
        [](auto& other) { 
                std::cout << "Processing (other)\n";
                display(std::cout, other);
            }
        );

    process_archive("archive.txt", visitor);
}
```

Prints

```
Processing (other)
display A3: 10 elements
Skipping A2 items, just because we can
display A1 or A2: 42
Processing (other)
display A1 or A2: data is a string here
Processing (other)
display A3: 10 elements
Processing (other)
display A1 or A2: data is a string here
Processing (other)
display A1 or A2: data is a string here
Processing (other)
display A3: 10 elements
Processing (other)
display A1 or A2: data is a string here
Processing (other)
display A3: 10 elements
Processing (other)
display A3: 10 elements
```

Comment: But this discriminates based on type, whereas the OP has values known only at runtime, no?

Comment: @ildjarn Mmm. Seems you're right. I've let myself be lead by scanning existing answers a little too much. Fixing...

Comment: @ildjarn Have updated the demonstration code to be more pertinent. I'll explain later - but I have to run now :)

Comment: Ah, I see; I suspected that this was the direction you were headed. +1, this is the most sensible solution thus far IMO.

Comment: Isn't the part the OP is asking about exactly the part that `boost::variant` does?

Comment: @Yakk I'm tempted to say "Isn't that exactly what my answer is about?" But yeah I still owe the OP some more rationale. I'm juggling family time at the moment.

Comment: A question about the implementation, vs. the answer as a whole: I'm curious about the `Overload` implementation in your initial answer vs. the `visitor_t` in subsequent revisions. Particularly, what are the tradeoffs of storing a functor and perfectly forwarding to it (as `Overload` does) vs inheriting from said functor and `using F::operator()` (as `visitor_t`)? My gut instinct is to prefer the former, but I'm sure I'm missing some practical considerations...

Comment: @ildjarn Excellent point. In my memory the two were identical, but you're right I made some different choices there. I'd say the pure inheritence version (as I copied it here) is better because it doesn't interpose a "perfect forwarding" barrier. This makes overload resolution a bit more "direct" ...

Comment: ... (see e.g. [Item 30: Familiarize yourself with perfect forwarding failure cases.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) from Scott Meyers Effective Modern C++. E.g. the argument deduction rules out implicit conversions of arguments). (_So, I'll edit in move-construction of the bases and roll with the version I selected accidentally :)_)

Comment: @sehe ... no, implicit conversion of arguments is fine.  Except `0` to pointer, and initializer list based construction, ODR invokations, overload function name resolution, and a few other cases like that.  Implicit conversion will still occur, however?

Comment: Note that the second specialization of `visitor_t` also needs `using typename boost::static_visitor<T>::result_type;` to avoid ambiguity in case any of the other functors also have a `result_type`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your existing solution isn't bad.  At the point of `// do generic stuff` instead call into other functions overloaded on type

```
boost::fusion::for_each(possible_types, [&](auto i) {
  if (i::typeidx != typeidx) { return; }
  doSpecificStuff(i);
});

void doSpecificStuff(const TypeA& a) { ... }
void doSpecificStuff(const TypeB& b) { ... }
...
```

AFAIK you can't quite get a `switch`, which is a little bit faster than the `if...else` structure here, but not substantially and is unlikely to be noticeable for a process you run while reading a file.

Other options are all similar to this.  Fusion or mpl random access containers or even std::tuple can be access with get<> but that requires a compile time index so you're building the cases up and still going through the indices with something like

```
if (idx == 0) { doSpecificStuff(std::get<0>(possible_types)); }
else if (idx == 1) ...
....
```

Which could be done with recursive templates, like:

```
template <size_t current>
void dispatchImpl(size_t idx)
{
    if (idx >= std::tuple_size<possible_types>::value) return;
    if (idx == current) 
    {
        doSpecificStuff(std::get<current>(possible_types));
        return;
    }
    dispatchImpl<current + 1>(idx);
}
void dispatch(size_t idx) { dispatchImpl<0>(idx); }
```

The only alternative I'm aware of would be building an array of function pointers.  See [Optimal way to access std::tuple element in runtime by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062864/optimal-way-to-access-stdtuple-element-in-runtime-by-index).  I don't think you really gain anything with that solution for your case and it's harder to follow.

One advantage to your `fusion::for_each` solution is that it doesn't force your type indices to be continuous.  As your application evolves you can add new types or remove old types easily and the code still works, which would be harder if you were trying to use the container index as your type index.

Answer (score 1):

When you say *I have the same generic code for different types*; is it possible to wrap it all into a function with same prototype?

If so, you can map each `type_index` with a `std::function` in order to make the compiler to generate code for each type and to have an easy way to call every function in replacement to a switch.

Switch replacement:

```
function_map.at(read())();
```

---

Running example:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Type>
void doGenericStuff() {
    std::cout << typeid(Type).name() << std::endl;
    // ...
}

class A {};
class B {};
enum class type_index {typeA, typeB};
const std::map<type_index, std::function<void()>> function_map {
    {type_index::typeA, doGenericStuff<A>},
    {type_index::typeB, doGenericStuff<B>},
};

type_index read(void) {
    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    return type_index(i);
}

int main(void) {
    function_map.at(read())(); // you must handle a possible std::out_of_range exception
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best thing would just be to use an array of functions that do what you want to do:

```
typedef std::tuple<type1, type2, ..., typeN> PossibleTypes;
typedef std::function<void()> Callback;

PossibleTypes possible_types;
std::array<Callback, std::tuple_size<PossibleTypes >::value> callbacks = {
    [&]{ doSomethingWith(std::get<0>(possible_types)); },
    [&]{ doSomethingElseWith(std::get<1>(possible_types)); },
    ...
};
```

That array is easy to generate with the help of [integer_sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), if all your calls are really the same:

```
template <typename... T, size_t... Is>
std::array<Callback, sizeof...(T)> makeCallbacksImpl(std::tuple<T...>& t,
                                                     integer_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return { [&]{ doSomethingWith(std::get<Is>(t)) }... };

    // or maybe if you want doSomethingWith<4>(std::get<4>(t)):
    // return { [&]{ doSomethingWith<Is>(std::get<Is>(t)) }... };

}

template <typename... T>
std::array<Callback, sizeof...(T)> makeCallbacks(std::tuple<T...>& t) {
    return makeCallbacksImpl(t, make_integer_sequence<sizeof...(T)>{});
}
```

And once we have our array, regardless of which way we generate, we just need to call it:

```
void genericStuffWithIdx(int idx) {
    if (idx >= 0 && idx < callbacks.size()) {
        callbacks[idx]();
    }
    else {
        // some error handler
    }
}
```

Or if throwing is good enough:

```
void genericStuffWithIdx(int idx) {
    callbacks.at(idx)(); // could throw std::out_of_range
}
```

You can't really beat array lookup on performance, although you do have indirection through `std::function<void()>`. This will definitely beat the fusion for_each solution, since there even if `idx == 0`, you're actually running through each element anyway. You would really want to use `any()` in that case, so you can quit early. But still faster to just use an array.

Answer (score 0):

Build an `unordered_map` from `type_index` to processing code.

Read the `type_index`, lookup in map, execute.  Error check for missing entries.

Simple, extendible, versionable -- simply add a length header on entries (make sure it handles 64 bit lengths -- have max lower bit count length mean real length is next, which allows single bit lengths to start), and if you do not understand an entry you can skip it.