# Practical limitations on amount of constexpr computation

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr, limits

As an experiment, I just put together some code to generate a `std::array<uint32_t, 256>` at compile time.  The table contents themselves are a fairly typical CRC lookup table - about the only new thing is the use of `constexpr` functions to calculate the entries as opposed to putting an autogenerated magic table directly in the source code.

Anyway, this exercise got me curious: would there be any practical limitations on the amount of computation a compiler would be willing to do to evaluate a `constexpr` function or variable definition at compile time?  e.g. something like gcc's `-ftemplate-depth` parameter creating practical limits on the amount of template metaprogramming evaluation.  (I also wonder if there might be practical limitations on the length of a parameter pack - which would limit the size of a compile-time `std::array` created using a `std::integer_sequence` intermediate object.)

Comment: If I recall xorrectly, yes there is a limit, but it is supposed to be orders of magnitude bigger than the recursive instantiation limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recommendations for such can be found in [[implimits] ¶2](http://eel.is/c++draft/implimits#2):

> (2.35)   —   Recursive constexpr function invocations [**512**]
>
> (2.36)   —   Full-expressions evaluated within a core constant expression [**1 048 576**]

GCC and Clang allow adjustment via `-fconstexpr-depth` (which is the flag you were looking for).

Constant expression evaluation practically runs in a sandbox, because [undefined behavior must be preempted by the implementation](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2). With that in mind, I don't see why the implementation couldn't use the entire resources of the host machine. Then again, I wouldn't recommend writing programs whose compilation requires gigabytes of memory or other unreasonable resources...

Comment: OK, would "Template arguments in a template declaration [1 024]" also count lengths of parameter packs?  (I'm guessing yes, otherwise you could only run into that limit with extremely badly written C++ code.)  If so, that would mean that building a `std::array<uint32_t, 65536>` lookup table to process two bytes at a time would probably not be practical.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I don't understand.

Comment: In the end, the table is created by a function `template <uint8_t... I> constexpr std::array<uint32_t, sizeof...(I)> crc_table_impl(uint32_t crc_poly, std::integer_sequence<uint8_t, I...>) { return { crc_table_entry(crc_poly, I)... }; }` being passed an `integer_sequence` containing 0 through 255.  So, if I tried to do the same thing with `uint16_t` there would be an intermediate template with 65537 arguments.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yeah, that's a weird plan. Why not just use a loop?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only valid way to initialize a `std::array` of an integral type within a `constexpr` function is to give all the elements from the beginning.  If I try using the default constructor gcc errors out with: `uninitialized variable ‘result’ in ‘constexpr’ function` (then going on to explain that the default constructor doesn't initialize the array).

Comment: I suppose if I used a class wrapper around `uint32_t` to make the default constructor initialize to 0 then the loop method could potentially work.

Comment: After more experimentation, it looks like with a class wrapper around `uint32_t`, and using C++17, the loop-based version would work.  (C++17 is where non-const `std::array::operator[]` is updated to `constexpr` - and even g++ 6.1.0 hasn't incorporated that update so I had to make a local copy of the `<array>` header and put it in myself - not the safest thing to do, though.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler: no, the template pack length doesn't count as depth in general, unless reading the list of parameters requires it that way. See for instance Yakk's comments to my answer in this question from long ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235855/switch-statement-variadic-template-expansion/32235928#32235928 Often times its easy to make an algorithm that manages a parameter pack of length `n` using depth `n`, but if you are clever sometimes the depth can be only `log n`. If you use constexpr stuff instead of templates for actual iteration then you circumvent the issue I think

Comment: @DanielSchepler `{}` is a valid initializer, as `array` is an aggregate (so each element will itself be initialized with `{}`, i.e. value-initialized). You don't need a wrapper.

Comment: @Columbo OK thanks, `std::array<uint32_t, 256> result = {};` does work.  That does still leave the issue that assigning to the array in a constexpr function requires C++17 features not yet in any of my available compilers.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Why not use a bog-standard array?

Comment: @Columbo According to gcc, a function is not allowed to return a language-level array: from `using table = uint32_t[256]; constexpr table my_arr() { ... }` I get `error: ‘my_arr’ declared as function returning an array`.