# The advantage of std::visit over if-else

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

I have figured out that std::visit can be used the following way:

```
    std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
        using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
            std::cout << "int with value " << arg << '\n';
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
            std::cout << "std::string with value " << std::quoted(arg) << '\n';
        else 
            static_assert(always_false_v<T>, "non-exhaustive visitor!");
    }, v);
```

But instead, I figured I could also just use

```
    if(auto x = std::get_if<int>(&v))
        std::cout << " is int " << *x << std::endl;
    else if(auto x = std::get_if<std::string>(&v))
        std::cout << " is String " << *x << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "non-exhaustive visitor!" << std::endl;
```

The only disadvantage that I see right now is that I do not have a static message for when my matching is not exhaustive. Is there any other advantage of using std::visit that I am not seeing?

Comment: "*Is there any other advantage of using std::visit that I am not seeing?*" `std::visit` can also handle *multiple* variants, and *can* visit classes derived from `std::variant`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is there any other advantage of using std::visit that I am not seeing?

Yes. With `std::visit` you can use the built-in function overload resolution instead of matching against all of the types manually:

```
template<typename... Fs> struct Overload: Fs... { using Fs::operator()...; };
template<typename... Fs> Overload(Fs...) -> Overload<Fs...>;

static_assert(visit(Overload{
    [](int) { return "int"; },
    [](std::string_view) { return "string_view"; },
    [](auto) { return "something else"; }
}, std::variant<int, std::string_view, bool, double>{42}) == "int"sv);
```

Also, `visit` might compile to faster code because of only one type match, but it should be checked whether the `if`s-version gets its multiple matches optimized away.

#### Update

As @Quentin mentioned in a comment,

> unlike the manual if ladders, an overload will be selected not if it is an exact match, but merely if it is callable (via conversions if needed)

If there is an overload where conversions are undesirable, this technique should help:

```
[](std::same_as<int> auto) {} // C++20
```

or

```
template<typename T, typename U> using SameAs = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, U>>;

[](auto t, SameAs<decltype(t), int>* = 0) {} // C++17
```

Comment: In case it isn't clear, removing the `auto` overload will catch missing types as requested. However it's worth noting that, unlike the manual `if` ladders, an overload will be selected not if it is an exact match, but merely if it is callable (via conversions if needed). IOW, visiting an `std::variant<float, int>` with only an `int` overload will compile and truncate a `float`.

Comment: In general the jump table *should* be generated at compile time which makes the code a bit faster. BUT I run into trouble with very slow code by having this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146629/optimizing-of-stdvisit-possible

Comment: I've updated the answer in case the effect described by @Quentin was a problem. Also added a missing deduction guide.